# .NET Производительность ReadAllText и SetBackgroundImage

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c++-cli

Есть у меня подозрения что ReadAllText работает неприемлемо плохо, дело в том что формы у меня появляются с изменением прозрачности от нуля к единице, и вот когда вызывается форма с TextBox"ом (без фоновых картинок), а в TextBox грузится txt файл размером 40кб очень заметны изменения в скорости изменения прозрачности

```
this->Opacity = i + 0.1;
```

Грубо говоря - тормозит! Не подумайте, компьютер у меня не слаб для данной операции.

Comment: Старайтесь задавать один вопрос в одном топике.

Comment: @Smirnov я вырезал тему 2 из вопроса. пожалуйста, оформляйте отдельные темы отдельными вопросами - тут так принято

Comment: омг. вопрос был один "Кто что может сказать по этому поводу?". И я уверен ответ будет касаться как 1ой темы так и 2ой...

Comment: ок - по этому поводу "в winforms, как и в остальных фреймворках, могут быть проблемы с производительностью, если код написан криво. покажите код"

Comment: Файловые операции всегда нужно делать в фоновом потоке. Если у юзера заснул винт, он не должен видеть зависший UI вашей программы. Производительность чтения с диска не гарантирует вам никто.

Comment: WinForms - использует GDI+. GDI+ не использует возможности и память видеокарты. TextBox - очень медленно работает с большими текстами. Ваше железо тут ни при чем. Просто не правильно использовали инструмент, или использовали неправильный инструмент, тут уж на вкус и цвет.